# Matplotlib backend shifts when using object detection API, QtAgg to Agg

Tags: python, matplotlib, virtualenv

The figure doesn't show up when using matplotlib with object detection API, But it works fine before I import some test method.

I'm using Anaconda virtual envionment, python 3.6 and the google object detection API.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow as tf

from matplotlib import patches

from object_detection.anchor_generators.multiple_grid_anchor_generator import create_ssd_anchors

from object_detection.models.ssd_mobilenet_v2_feature_extractor_test import SsdMobilenetV2FeatureExtractorTest

from object_detection.models.ssd_mobilenet_v2_feature_extractor_test import SsdMobilenetV2FeatureExtractorTest
```

The change happens when it comes to the last line

```
from object_detection.models.ssd_mobilenet_v2_feature_extractor_test import SsdMobilenetV2FeatureExtractorTest"
```

Before, I can show the figure, like plt.subplot(2,2), I get the figure pop up and the following:

```
(<Figure size 640x480 with 4 Axes>,
array([[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f4615eb8ba8>,
     <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f4614d320f0>],
    [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f4614ce36a0>,
     <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f4614c92c50>]],
   dtype=object))
WARNING: The TensorFlow contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0.
For more information, please see:
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/addons
```

If you depend on functionality not listed there, please file an issue.

and "plt.get_backend()" shows "Qt5Agg".
but after the last line, the figure doesn't pop up, although I do get results from "plt.subplots(2,2)":

```
(<Figure size 640x480 with 4 Axes>,
 array([[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f460b8a5f60>,
     <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f460b86b5c0>],
    [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f460a7b2fd0>,
     <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f460a7cb630>]],
   dtype=object))
```

Now when I type "plt.get_backend()", it shows "Agg", not the previous "Qt5Agg". and "plt.show()" throws an error:

```
UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
  #!/usr/bin/env python2
```

the interpreter I was using is

```
~/anaconda3/envs/py36/bin/python
```

Is there a shift of environment here?

The script for the last line can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/models/ssd_mobilenet_v2_feature_extractor_test.py)

Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 3):

Solved. Have found this line in ~/models/research/object_detecion/utils/visualization_utils.py :

```
import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('Agg')  # pylint: disable=multiple-statements
```

just comment it and works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Solved. I am running locally on a virtual enironment and tried several suggested solution but with no success.
I tried what Yunfei Fang was suggesting above but then realized that by, commenting out the line of code `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('Agg')`  in the ~/models/research/object_detecion/utils/visualization_utils.py folder wasn't enough.
I found out by putting this code in the body of my script: `print('matplotlib backend= ',matplotlib.get_backend())` as this was still returning "agg" so I had to add this `matplotlib.use('MacOSX')` at the end of the import section of the script.
I am running on a MacBook Pro with macOS Big Sur

Comment: This is what is so great about Stack Overflow.  Thank you!